# PHP preg_replace any text in replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, replace

How to replace text with **any** text and symbols in replacement? Because when i use **backslash** it`s badly replaced.

```
$text = 'hello replacement world';

$text = preg_replace('#replacement#ui', '28\01\12', $text);
```

Result

```
hello 28 world
```

Solution to do replace before using pattern

```
$pattern = '28\01\12';
$pattern = str_replace('\\', '\\\\\\\\', $pattern);
```

**This is just expample, in real work need to use more complicated pattern and replacement will consist any text**

Comment: Why are you using preg_replace? For this case a simple str_replace will be much faster.

Comment: pattern more complicated, it`s example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('#replacement#ui', '28\\01\\12', $text);
```

See the notes here on backslashes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

If you're just searching for a simple string to replace, you should consider using `str_replace()` instead. It's less expensive cpu-wise. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

**UPDATE:** More info on escape sequences: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: Ok, works with $text = preg_replace('#replacement#ui', '28\\\\01\\\\12', $text); I need to use preg_replace cause pattern more complicated. Please, tell me, what another symbols i need to escape to avoid problems?

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'hello replacement world';

$text = preg_replace('#replacement#ui', '28\\01\\12', $text);
```

This happens because you have to escape the backslash in the string.

Comment: Ok, works with $text = preg_replace('#replacement#ui', '28\\\\01\\\\12', $text); I need to use preg_replace cause pattern more complicated. Please, tell me, what another symbols i need to escape to avoid problems?